# Regular expression pattern (match newline and tab) in Python

Tags: python, regex

I am using Python.
Please help me to find Regex pattern for this:

```
SELECT
    SELECT select1
    FROM
        SELECT A
        FROM B
        WHERE C
    WHERE X
FROM
    SELECT from1
    FROM from2
    WHERE from3
WHERE
    SELECT child1
    FROM child2
```

I want to take out three parts:

```
SELECT select1
FROM
    SELECT A
    FROM B
    WHERE C
WHERE X
```

and

```
    SELECT from1
    FROM from2
    WHERE from3
```

and

```
    SELECT child1
    FROM child2
```

With each part that I took out, I'll do a recursive call to do the same stuff again. :)

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Where is the Regex that you've already tried? We are not working on your homework without you trying anything here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex will work for you

```
(?=\t)((?:.|\n\t+)*)
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uZ1wD9/1)**

*Regex Breakdown*

```
(?=\t) #This lookahead finds the position of \t
  (    #Capturing group
    (?: #Non-capturing group
      .  #Match any character (but this does not matches \n.So we use alternation)
     |  #Alternation (OR)
      \n\t+ #Match all lines \n followed by \t (as it seems from your input)
    )* #Repeat this until any of the condition (mainly \n followed by \t) fails
  )
```

**NOTE** :- While using this in python make sure that it is `\t` only and not simple space.

*Python Code*

```
p = re.compile(r'(?=\t)((?:.|\n\t+)*)', re.MULTILINE)
test_str = "SELECT\n\tSELECT select1\n\tFROM\n\t\tSELECT A\n\t\tFROM B\n\t\tWHERE C\n\tWHERE X\nFROM\n\tSELECT from1\n\tFROM from2\n\tWHERE from3\nWHERE\n\tSELECT child1\n\tFROM child2"
print(re.findall(p, test_str))
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/vXXI3d)**

Comment: It works perfectly :)! But can you explain your code for me?

Comment: your regex, i don't under stand `?:.|\n\t+` part!

Comment: @tuankhoa1996 you can also upvote the answer by clicking on up arrow..also you need to strip away one `\t` from the final output to match your exact format

Answer (score 0):

It's super simple:`^\s(.*)`

Here's how to use it in code:

```
import re

str = "Your text here"
p = re.compile(ur'^\s(.*), re.MULTILINE)
re.findall(p, str)
```

## Explanation

- `^` Anchor to line start
- `\s` Match a space
- `(.*)` Match everything until end of line

Comment: while it seem to work on regex 101..it is capturing each line